# Jenkins UCM Clearcase - multiple streams

Tags: jenkins, stream, clearcase-ucm, vob

I am using Jenkins - UCM clearCase plugin. 
I have two streams - One for Code and one for config and build scipts.

**Stream selector:**  stream_code_name@\vob

**load rules:**

```
         load set_code

         load set_config
```

set_code is for stream_code_name stream.

Note: Jenkins downloaded the code under VIEWTAG/set_code. I want config code under VIEWTAG/set_config.

How do I load another stream ie **stream_config_name@\vob.** ??

I am open to using another plugins or base clearcase plugin too.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason why an UCM stream `stream_code_name@\vob` does *not* load anything under `set_config`, even though its config spec has a load rule is... there is no `set_config` component (no UCM component with a root folder set_config)

You need to rebase that stream with a foundation baseline of a component including `set_config` folder in order for that stream, when loaded (by Jenkins or even manually, on your own computer), to display any file in `set_config`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the actual question. Its the workaround I used to overcome the situation. I created another project for **stream_config_name@\vob**.

load rules:

```
load set_config
```

Then added this subproject as dependent project to my codeStream Jenkins project. When the code stream project is triggered, configStream project is triggered and hence config data is also downloaded.